# Does the tor browser or tails makes my computer part of a tor relay or exit node by default?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, tails

The subject line says it all. I want the tor browser or tails to be just clients. Is there a way to check the settings if the tor browser and tails are being used as clients only. Thanks